# .NET 7.0 iOS and Android Workloads NETSDK1202

Tags: .net, .net-6.0, maui, .net-7.0

I'm creating a new mobile app using .NET.

I originally installed the iOS and Android workloads using .NET 6 but I saw the NETSDK1202 warning about these workloads being unsupported now in .NET 6. To solve this I updated the target framework to be `net7.0-ios` and `net7.0-android`.

However I am still seeing the NETSDK1202 warning when building the app using .NET 7. Im not sure why this is as although the projects were originally created using the .NET 6 workloads they should now be built using .NET 7?

Answer (score 0):

NETSDK1202 indicates your project is using an optional workload that is out of support.

You can continue building net6.0 .NET MAUI applications with a .NET 6 or .NET 7 SDK in an unsupported fashion. Additionally, you can opt out of the warning in a project with the setting:

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <CheckEolWorkloads>false</CheckEolWorkloads>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more details, you can refer to [NETSDK1202: workload is out of support and will not receive security updates in the future](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/sdk-errors/netsdk1202).

Comment: My question was more around why I'm receiving the warning when I'm targeting .NET 7 as it isn't out of support?

Comment: @MobileDev Thanks for the response, .NET 7 is in the standard term support, however, have you tried to add  `<CheckEolWorkloads>false</CheckEolWorkloads>` to see if it can remove the warning?

Comment: May I know whether your issue has been solved or not? If not, please share it in here. We can work together to figure it out.

Comment: I think my issues was because we still have some projects targeting .NET 6. Now all projects have been updated to .NET 7 we no longer see the warning.

Comment: @MobileDev Thanks for the response, good to see you no longer see the warnings after switching to NET 7.